# Why does Keras perceive my input_shape as three dimensional when I only have two inputs?

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, error-handling, neural-network

**This is the ValueError that I'm currently experiencing:**

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_10 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 9]
```

It should be noted that I am working out of R using Keras, Caret, and Tidyverse.

I'm currently building a neural network model on the Titanic dataset in Kaggle.

- [This is the link to my Kaggle notebook and dataset.](https://www.kaggle.com/blakelucey/neural-network-titanic)
- Following this link will provide you with all of the code I have written so far as well as the complete dataset that I am working with.

From the ValueError that was thrown I understand that there is an issue with how I am describing the shape of my `X.train` data.  Although, I'm not sure how to shape this data so that my model runs smoothly.

The following is how I have begun to build my model:

```
#Build Model
input_shape <- shape(ncol(X.train), nrow(X.train))
                     
model <- keras_model_sequential()

model %>%
    layer_batch_normalization(input_shape = input_shape) %>% #Normalization Layer
    layer_dense(units = 256, activation = 'relu') %>%  #First Layer
    layer_batch_normalization() %>%
    layer_dropout(rate = 0.3) %>% 
    layer_dense(units = 256, activation = 'relu') %>% #Second layer
    layer_batch_normalization() %>%
    layer_dropout(rate = 0.3) %>%
    layer_dense(units = 256, activation = 'relu') %>% #Third layer
    layer_batch_normalization() %>%
    layer_dropout(rate = 0.3) %>%
    layer_dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid') %>% #Output Layer
    compile(
      loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
      optimizer = 'adam',
      metrics = c('accuracy'))
```

This is the full error that I am experiencing:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_10 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 9]


Detailed traceback: 
  File "/usr/local/share/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 108, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/share/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1098, in fit
    tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
  File "/usr/local/share/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 780, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/share/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 823, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "/usr/local/share/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 697, in _initialize
    *args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/local/share/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2855, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/share/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3213, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/share/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3075, in _create_graph_function
    capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
  File "/usr/local/share/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 986, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/share/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 600, in wrapped_fn
    return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/share/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 973, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)

Traceback:

1. model %>% fit(X.train, y.train, epochs = 500, batch_size = 200, 
 .     validation_split = 0.3, callbacks = list(callback_early_stopping(monitor = "val_loss", 
 .         mode = "auto", patience = 5, min_delta = 0.001, restore_best_weights = TRUE)))
2. withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env))
3. eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
4. eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
5. `_fseq`(`_lhs`)
6. freduce(value, `_function_list`)
7. withVisible(function_list[[k]](value))
8. function_list[[k]](value)
9. fit(., X.train, y.train, epochs = 500, batch_size = 200, validation_split = 0.3, 
 .     callbacks = list(callback_early_stopping(monitor = "val_loss", 
 .         mode = "auto", patience = 5, min_delta = 0.001, restore_best_weights = TRUE)))
10. fit.keras.engine.training.Model(., X.train, y.train, epochs = 500, 
  .     batch_size = 200, validation_split = 0.3, callbacks = list(callback_early_stopping(monitor = "val_loss", 
  .         mode = "auto", patience = 5, min_delta = 0.001, restore_best_weights = TRUE)))
11. do.call(object$fit, args)
12. (structure(function (...) 
  . {
  .     dots <- py_resolve_dots(list(...))
  .     result <- py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords)
  .     if (convert) 
  .         result <- py_to_r(result)
  .     if (is.null(result)) 
  .         invisible(result)
  .     else result
  . }, class = c("python.builtin.method", "python.builtin.object"
  . ), py_object = <environment>))(batch_size = 200L, epochs = 500L, 
  .     verbose = 1L, callbacks = list(<environment>, <environment>), 
  .     validation_split = 0.3, shuffle = TRUE, class_weight = NULL, 
  .     sample_weight = NULL, initial_epoch = 0L, x = <environment>, 
  .     y = <environment>)
13. py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords)
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords): ValueError: in user code: /usr/local/share/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:806 train_function * return step_function(self, iterator) /usr/local/share/.virtual
keyboard_arrow_right
```

Thank you, I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: The input shape does not contain the batch or samples dimension, Keras adds it automatically

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy How can I fix this so that I have a two-dimensional shape? Do I need to further define input_shape to include missing inputs?